# What is wrong with MySql Syntax,

Tags: php, mysql

Can someone please help me what is wrong with this syntax.
when i run this, it doesn't insert the values into the table.

Currently all the variables e.g `$land`, etc have a value.
in my database table, all except `$nOwners,$id(int)` are defined as `varchar`, .

Details:
 I am using `Mysqli`

```
$sql= "INSERT into property_list (id, title_no, status, register_type, type,land_district, issue_date,guarantee_status,provisional,title_no_srs,title_no_head_srs, survey_reference, Maori_land, number_owners) 
       VALUES($id,'$title', '$status', '$register', '$type', '$land', '$issue_date', '$guarantee', '$provision', '$title_no_srs','$head_srs', '$survery', '$maori', $nOwners)"; 


if($conn->query($sql)!==false)
{
    $flag=false;
    echo "successfully inserted ";
}
```

Comment: [Obligatory](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: ^ obligatory? where's this written? I don't remember signing a contract ;-) ...or, did I?

Comment: In my mind. Every time someone commits the crime of not escaping variables and not using prepared statements, Bobby Tables must be linked. It is a law.

Comment: Your code may contain syntax errors of you've something that MySQL may be complaining about. 
Consult these following links http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
and apply that to your code.

Comment: to be fair(i know this is unlike me) as we don't see what happens to the variable before the query, they could all be sanatised

Comment: Plus, looking at all those columns and variables, I didn't go in and count those. If there's a column mismatch count, well there you go.

Comment: Print the SQL statement after variable substitution.  95% of the time,the answer is then obvious.

Comment: *"Details: I am using Mysqli"* - Ok and what about your connection?

Comment: It does connects to my database.

Comment: echo out `$sql`. Assuming you even get that far

Comment: well then, no problem then. There's nothing more to see folks, carry on.

Comment: maybe we are talking past each other.  It does connect to my database but it does not insert content/data into my table. the issue is with insert.

Comment: ask the guy who's given you an answer below then. He seems to know more than I do. Good luck. Edit: Notice the upvote on my comment up there? that's a hint.

Comment: @mario - what reserved word is that which you closed the question with? I see `status` and `name` and `type`. Those are keywords, not reserved words. What am I missing or not grasping here?

Comment: @Drew I voted as "why it's not working", not the reserved word issue which it isn't. Mario and I both hold a gold for questions like that; notice the gold next to his name and not mine? ;-) there you go. Had I closed it with that, then my name would have the gold icon next to it. That's why my name also appears next to the dupe.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I just thought the unquoted column names most probable still, thus just closed it with that. It's as good a guess as any. (Only OP can tell if he bothered to follow the `mysqli_error` advise, or showed all relevant code and input values, table scheme etc.)

Comment: can you edit the question, show error reporting info turned on (or not), show more of the php file. We can suggest an edit even if thru pastie

Comment: @mario Fair enough. The OP has been given enough information to debug their code. Ok... I am now heading for runway 1030, riding on 148 heavy. *ciao for now*

Answer (score -1):

Hmm, the column name status might be an issue, it is a reserved keyword in sql. Try another name and see if that fixes it. 
https://www.drupal.org/node/141051

Comment: `name` is a keyword and not a reserved word https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html - Notice the `(R)` that is NOT next to it?

Comment: that isn't my downvote btw. which I just noticed now.

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/node/141051 *"List of SQL reserved words"* - SQL is not MySQL. Those are two different animals altogether. Noticed this link http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html on the same page as your link?

Comment: That page contains a compilation of many SQL sources, including mysql

Comment: It seems I am only blowing bubbles. Ok, whatever you say then, you're the Grand SQL/MySQL/Oracle/MSSQL Wizard.